# Detect Children Controls under mouse in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

I have a WPF `ParentUserControl` and some `ChildUserControlA` `ChildUserControlB` etc. (also WPF controls)

The `ChildUserControl`s are controls containing on them some other basic elements (textboxes, labels, etc)

In the main form's status bar I need to display the name of the currenlty mouse overed *ChildUserControl*.

So, in the *ParentUserControl*'s MouseMove I obtain an object `myElement = Mouse.DirectlyOver` because I need the top most of **ChildUserControl**'s, but I obtain instead a 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (part of ChildUserControl)...

How to fix that?

I need when I mouseOver an MyChildControl that the MyChildControl be detected, and not its child elements.

In this order I used on MyChildControl the following:

```
Protected Overrides Function HitTestCore(
                    hitTestParameters As PointHitTestParameters) As HitTestResult

    Return New PointHitTestResult(Me, hitTestParameters.HitPoint)
End Function
```

but anyway I get sometimes the textblock as result, sometimes the ChildUserControl...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer may be something like this - define the exact types of objects you care about and work up the visual tree until you find them :

```
Private myTypes As New List(Of Type)()
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    myTypes.Add(GetType(ComboBox))
    myTypes.Add(GetType(CheckBox))
    myTypes.Add(GetType(RadioButton))
    myTypes.Add(GetType(TabControl))
    myTypes.Add(GetType(Button))
    myTypes.Add(GetType(Label))
    myTypes.Add(GetType(GroupBox))
    myTypes.Add(GetType(Window))
End Sub

Private Sub Window_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    Dim x As DependencyObject = _
      DirectCast(e.MouseDevice.DirectlyOver, DependencyObject)
    Dim t As Type = x.GetType
    While Not myTypes.Contains(t)
         x = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(x)
         If x Is Nothing Then Exit While
         t = x.GetType
    End While

    If x IsNot Nothing Then
          Console.WriteLine(x.ToString())
    Else
          Console.WriteLine("Nothing")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement [Hit-Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit-testing). So if you want to get all the elements that are inside a region you can use [HitTestResultCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.hittestresultcallback%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). An example:

```
Dim Elements As New List(Of FrameworkElement)


Public Function GetVisuals(ByVal Region As Geometry) As List(Of FrameworkElement)

    If Region Is Nothing Then Return Nothing

    Dim Parameters As New GeometryHitTestParameters(Region)
    Elements.Clear()

    Dim Callback As New HitTestResultCallback(AddressOf Me.HitTestCallBack)
    VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(Me.ParentUserControl, Nothing, Callback, Parameters)

    Return Me.Elements

End Function

Private Function HitTestCallBack(ByVal Result As HitTestResult) As HitTestResultBehavior

    If Result IsNot Nothing Then

        Dim GeometryRes As GeometryHitTestResult = CType(Result, GeometryHitTestResult)
        Dim Element As FrameworkElement = TryCast(Result.VisualHit, FrameworkElement)

        If Element IsNot Nothing AndAlso GeometryRes.IntersectionDetail = IntersectionDetail.FullyContains Then
            Me.Elements.Add(Element)
        End If

    End If

    Return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue

End Function
```

In this way the Elements list contains all the elements specified by [GeometryHitTestResult.IntersectionDetail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometryhittestresult.intersectiondetail%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), and if you want (for example) know the elements under the mouse position (MouseDown Event) just do so simply:

```
Dim Region As New RectangleGeometry(New Rect(e.GetPosition(Me.MyGrid), New Size(1, 1)))
Dim Elements As List(Of FrameworkElement) = Me.GetVisuals(Region)
```

This is what I mean in my comment:

```
Public Class DrawingCanvas
Inherits Panel

Public Function GetVisuals(ByVal Region As Geometry) As List(Of DrawingVisual)
End Function

Private Function HitTestCallBack(ByVal Result As HitTestResult) As HitTestResultBehavior
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: You could implement hit-testing anywhere in your control class, but it would be better, to make it reusable, make a class that inherits Panel and place the code there (in this case you have to replace Me.ParentUserControl with Me).

Comment: an UserControl is not a CustomControl, it can't inherit a Panel... A "panel" even does not exist in WPF...

Comment: You have not to do a new UserControl library, but just a "class" that inherits [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx).. But then again, it is not necessary

Comment: What kind of "Panel" do you mean? `System.Windows.Forms.Panel`?

Comment: We talk about WPF, not about WinForms, gliderkite )

Comment: I can't inherit a UserControl from a Panel... anyway, thank you.

Comment: My DrawingCanvas is NOT a UserControl, but you can use as your new childs container (like Grid, StackPanel, ...). Anyway read the [Panel overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx), will all be clear.

Comment: Your DrawingCanvas maybe is not, but in the Question was mentioned a UserControl, so your recomentation can't be applied to the question above.

Comment: Read my first comment, it's all written in my answer and there. It's useless to add other comments. Bye.